# GTM publish tags are not firing in website

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

[TAG SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwfYt.png)
I have a tag which is firing in preview debugger mode and script is lording as well. but on live site it is not working. tags are published.TAG SS is attached

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct GTM include for the live environment installed?

Comment: yes GTM is correctly included for the live environment.